# How can I search geo objects within donut shape with MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, geojson, geo

I have a list of documents in MongoDb with geo coordinates. And I want to find documents with limiting min and max distance. It looks like a donut shape, see the bottom of the page - http://blog.mongodb.org/post/50984169045/new-geo-features-in-mongodb-2-4

But how can I make a query to MongoDb if I only have my geo position, min and max distance?

Only thing I can now, is to limit documents with $maxDistance, but I have no min distance.

Please, help.

Comment: It seems like in Mongo 2.5 there is a $minDistance attr.

Comment: Do you know how to update mongoDB to 2.5 ?

Comment: I just downloded binaries. And it is works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

All I need is Mongo 2.5 or later.